# Compare two text files for mapped drives and assign if missing

Tags: powershell

I have a script that checks user's mapped drives. What I need the script to do is compare the users current mapped drives to a text file that has the drive letters and paths and add if any of them is missing. If I do a get-content for that text file i get something similar below. After the drive letter there are N amount of spaces. So splitting them to two variables needs some regex which I couldn't figure it out.

```
G  \\blahblah\blahb\blah      
H  \\blahblah\blah\blah
I  \\blahblah\blalah\blah           
L  \\blahblah\bla\blah       
W  \\blahblah\blaah\blah            
Y  \\blahblah\baah\blah
```

All I have for code at the moment is below. I tried lots of things but couldn't get anywhere. 
Thank you everyone in advance.

```
$drives = @(Get-content "C:\temp\drives.txt")

Write-Host "Comparing network drives and adding missing ones"
$MappedDrives = Get-PSDrive | Where-Object{$_.DisplayRoot -match ('\\\w*')} |`
  Format-Table -Property Name,DisplayRoot -AutoSize -HideTableHeaders

Foreach($lines in $mappedDrives){
  IF($lines -ne $drives)
  {
    New-PSDrive –Name $_ –PSProvider FileSystem –Root "\\blah\blah\blah" –Persist
  }
```

Comment: Do not use `Format-anything` cmdlets if you are going to process more data. They destory the objects. They exists for output only.

Comment: Yes it will Matt. From the `help get-psdrive` description: `Get-PSDrive gets the following types of drives:
    
    -- Windows logical drives on the computer, including drives mapped to network shares.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, like you said, this would probably be simplest with a RegEx match (in my opinion). I'd build a HashTable and then reference that to verify/map your drive letters.

So something like:

```
$Drives = @{}
Get-Content c:\temp\drives.txt | Where{$_ -match "^(.)\s+?(\\.+)"} | ForEach{$Drives.Add($matches[1],$matches[2].trim()}
```

Ok, we now have a list of desired drives. Next to compare against what you already have. You know how to get drives, but as already pointed out by Matt you're doing it wrong. Well, kind of. You get the data, but if you are going to store the data you need to store the object, and not pipe to Format-* (so, no Format-Table, Format-List, Format-Tacos, etc. Ok, there is no Format-Tacos, but there should be, tacos are delicious). But the base command you have is good, we'll work with that.

```
$MappedDrives = Get-PSDrive | Where-Object{$_.DisplayRoot -match ('\\\w*')}
```

So now we can reference that as an object, which is good. Let's check to see if there are any drives that are mapped to letters, that don't match the path we want:

```
$Conflicts = $MappedDrives | Where{$Drives.keys -contains $_.Name} | ForEach{If($Drives.($_.Name) -notmatch $_.Root.trimend("\")){[PSCustomObject]@{'DriveLetter'=$_.Name;'DesignatedPath'=$Drives.($_.Name);'CurrentPath'=$_.Root}}
If($conflicts.count -gt 0){"At least one drive is incorrectly mapped, see below:";$Conflicts|FT}
```

After that we map the rest:

```
$Drives.Keys | Where{$Conflicts.DriveLetter -notcontains $_} | ForEach{
    New-PSDrive –Name $_ –PSProvider FileSystem –Root $Drives.$_ –Persist
}
```

Comment: Format-Tacos..... Good work. I was going to do the same thing. With keys... not tacos

Comment: I literally spit my coffee to my screen when I read the "Format-Tacos" hahaa. Anyway, when I tried your has table in the beginning I got an error message Exception calling "Add" with "2" argument(s): "Key cannot be null.
Parameter name: key"

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot to fix that. It's updated now and should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

To start we convert your text data into a hashtable.

```
$desiredMappedDrives =  Get-Content C:\temp\drives.txt | ForEach-Object{
    $regex = [regex]"\s+"
    $regex.Replace($_,"=",1) -replace "\\","\\"
} | ConvertFrom-StringData
```

If you look at the value of `$desiredMappedDrives`:

```
Name                           Value                                                           
----                           -----                                                           
G                              \\blahblah\blahb\blah                                           
H                              \\blahblah\blah\blah                                            
I                              \\blahblah\blalah\blah                                          
L                              \\blahblah\bla\blah                                             
W                              \\blahblah\blaah\blah                                           
Y                              \\blahblah\baah\blah
```

What that allows you to do is compare each current drive to that of the list. Again, remove the `Format-Table` cmdlet.

```
$MappedDrives = Get-PSDrive | Where-Object{$_.DisplayRoot -match ('\\\w*')}
```

The rest of this answer was going to be the same as TheMadTechnicians. The only reason to leave it here as it provided a different approach to making the hashtable and that I did some work. *Tip hats* at TheMad

Comment: Matt, Thank you for this info. Now I'm wondering if it would make sense to format current mapped drives the same style with your desiredmappeddrives and use @TheMadTechnician 's way to compare and add?

Comment: @Besiktas I wouldnt think so. The purpose of the hashtable in this case was just to make it into an object for easy manipulation. `$MappedDrives` is already an object. Again, his answer is what i was in the middle of typing. It's quite possible that you could replace `$drives` in mad's code with my `$desiredMappedDrives` and it would function the same