# Automating MS Updates with Powershell

Tags: powershell, text, extract, filenames

I am trying to Automate my Microsoft update process based on the KB/MSU packages I download. I have a WMIC csv file that I am able to install based on simple If else statement. I would like to use the list extract just the "KBXXXXX" from the downloaded files and compare it to the list of installed KBs and discover what is missing.

KB install List (WMIC output):

```
KB123456
KB234567
KB345678
```

Downloaded KB file list format $KBUpdateList:
Name

```
WINDOWS6.1-KB2533552-X64.MSU                                                                                       
WINDOWS6.1-KB2533552-X86.MSU                                                                                       
WINDOWS6.1-KB2539635-X64.MSU                                                                                       
Windows6.1-KB958488-v6001-x64.MSU
```

Here is what I have that is not working to pull KB number:

PowerShell script to list the MSU files under the selected folder:

```
$Dir = get-childitem $folder -recurse
$KBUpdateList = $Dir | where {$_.extension -eq ".msu"}
$KBUpdatenames = $KBUpdateList | format-table name 
$KBNumberonly = $KBUpdateList.split("-")[1]
```

The split fails and I can't find a fix.  I just want to return the KBXXXX number so I can run my foreach statement that follows.  Thank You

Comment: For starters dont do this `$KBUpdatenames = $KBUpdateList | format-table name`. __Never__ assign output from `Format-[anything]` to a variable as it wrecks havoc on output. `Format-[anything]` is for good looking console output and thats all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should suffice for what you are looking for.

```
$KBUpdatenames = get-childitem $folder -recurse -Filter "*.msu" | Select-Object -Expand Name
$KBNumberonly = $KBUpdatenames | ForEach-Object{$_.split("-")[1]}
```

Use `Get-ChildItem` to get the files of type ".msu". Using `-Filter` is more efficient than `Where-Object` in most case where you are just looking for extensions. Then we expand just the names of the files with `Select-Object`

As for the `Format-Table` in your code I will refer you to an answer about [Format-Taco](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26639814/3829407) that I enjoy.

Comment: This is the error I get:Method invocation failed because [System.Object[]] doesn't contain a method named 'split'.
At C:\scripts\UpdateVM.ps1:53 char:36
+ $KBNumberonly = $KBUpdateList.split <<<< ("-")[1]
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (split:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound

Comment: oops... hold on.. copied code wrong.  @Tested4Noobs try again.